# Refresh PowerPivot through VSTO Addin that downloads an excel binary

Tags: c#, vsto, ms-office

I'm looking to create a VSTO addin for Excel that will allow the user to simply click on a button to get it refresh all the data in a spreadsheet in a way that doesn't break PowerPivot.

For reasons beyond my control, the excel data must be downloaded from a website.

ie. 
1. User clicks "Refresh Data" button
2. code connects to https://xxxxxx.yyyyy.zzzz/xyz
3. code then downloads the Excel binary
4. code takes the downloaded binary and refreshes the data in the currently open spreadsheet.

Comment: Can you provide more details? User clicks 'Refresh Data' within Excel Workbook #1, and that causes Excel Workbook #2 (binary) to be downloaded? Or are you describing User clicks 'Refresh Data' within an Excel workbook, and that causes Excel to connect to a remote site to download new data (not an excel binary), which needs to be added into the PivotCache.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider downloading and modifying the code from the [Excel Refresher Service](https://excelrefresher.codeplex.com/) - it contains the logic from opening a workbook and refreshing the PowerPivot cube... the web download part is on you :)